# Undefined reference to DLL function after it was exported and imported

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

So, I have a problem. I'm learning to use CMake, I have 2 projects, one compiles to a .dll file and the other one links to the .dll and compiles as a .exe executable. I Have a function `Run` in the dll code, I __declspec(dllexport) it and then import it in the .exe code but I get this error when compiling the .exe code

```
CMakeFiles\Editor.dir/objects.a(Editor.cpp.obj):Editor.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__imp__Z3Runv'
```

I have been looking through the entire internet, deleted the project, started again, again deleted it and started again, I went even through the 3rd page of google and couldn't find a solution that worked.

First of all, here is the structure of the Project:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSLIe.png)

`Copper Engine/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
#General intialization of CMake and the Project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project(Copper)

#Defines
add_compile_definitions(CU_BUILD_DLL)

#The main File will be compiled as a Shared Library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED src/Copper.h)

#Add Subdirectories
add_subdirectory(src/Copper)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} copper)
```

This all goes good, the subdirectory src/Copper is just `add_library(copper <FILES>)` and that also works. Now here is the file `Core.h`:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef CU_BUILD_DLL
    #define COPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define COPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

This is the important part since CU_BUILD_DLL is only defined in the dll project so when that compiles it should replace all of the code with "__declspec(dllexport)" and then when the executable gets compiled it should replace it with "__declspec(dllimport)".
Here is the `Application.h and Application.cpp`:

```
-----Application.h-----
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Core.h"

COPPER_API void Run();

-----Application.cpp-----
#include "Application.h"

void Run() {

    std::cout << "Succesfully called the Run function in Copper Engine Library!" << std::endl;

}
```

And no, this is not only one file, I only copied two files here so that it won't be so long. As you see, I declare and export the function and then define it in the .cpp file.

Now here is the `Copper Editor/CMakeLists.txt`

```
#General intialization of CMake and the Project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project(Editor)

#Find Needed Libraries
find_library(CopperEngine libCopper.dll NAMES Copper PATHS "../Build/Copper Editor")

#Check if we found the Libraries
if(${CopperEngine} STREQUAL CopperEngine-NOTFOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "----- Copper Engine Library not found! -----")
else()
    message(STATUS "----- Copper Engine Library found as ${CopperEngine}! -----")
endif()

#The main File will be compiled as an executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Editor.cpp)

#Add Include directiories to the Target
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "../Copper Engine/src")

#Link Libraries to the Target
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Build/Copper Editor/libCopper.dll")
```

There are also no errors when CMake-ing this file. Now here is the Main file of the .exe project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Copper.h>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    Run();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

The `Copper.h` file just includes the `Application.h` file so that I can get the declaration of the Run function but this time with `__declspec(dllimport)`

Now, when I compile the Editor I have an error with the Run function:

```
CMakeFiles\Editor.dir/objects.a(Editor.cpp.obj):Editor.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__imp__Z3Runv'
```

As I said, I only started learning CMake so probably it's something incredibly simple but I'm just too dumb for it. Also, I know, I saw that I shouldn't use .dll files with CMake but I want to use them to mainly gain experience and I will probably later switch to just plain .lib files.

Also, As I said I literally went through the 2nd and 3rd page of google and couldn't find anything, I already spent 2 days working on it and I just can't figure it out. Also I would like to keep the general structure of the code, if it's possible. And I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Code. If you need to know anything else I will gladly edit this post to include it or answer it in the comments.

Thanks for any kind of response.

Comment: `objects.a` smells like OBJECT library. Since your `Copper Editor/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't create the library, then it seems you actually build some **other code**. Other notes: 1. The second parameter to `find_library` should be either a single library name or be NAMES which enumerates several names. 2. Check for successful call to find_library is performed with `if(CopperEngine)` (plain variable name). 3. In the `target_link_libraries` use **result** of `find_library` call (`${CopperEngine}`) instead of repeating the path to the library.

Comment: You are just creating 2 "copper" dlls. As you say your add_subdirectory contains another call to add_library with lowercase copper. The outer lib copper has only Copper.h as source file

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for response, I checked the engine code and it's insde CMake/Copper.dir and it is in both projects so I assume it's a port of the linkeing or compiling proccess, it's also alongside with .obj files, but I don't know alot about CMake, but I will research it more.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I accidentally sent the previous comment but about the other notes. 1. I had more names there previously but I deleted them just because I was testing some stuff and it didn't seem to change anything.2. Honestly this check is from CMake tutorial series that I went through and it's a bit outdated, but it works fine, and also in their version the thing you suggested didn't work so I just went with this just in case it still didn't work, but thanks for letting me know.3. And I also know about that, I just didn't get to change it because first I want it to work and this worked previously

Comment: @sego but the lowercase copper library is linked to the main library, and it is not a .dll library but a .a library, this is how I saw it's done when you want to add a new folder with source files to the source folder. And it also worked when I harcoded the dllexport and then dllimport in the .exe code

Comment: @sego I found out the issue, I moved the files that contain the Run function and compiled them with the main .h file and it worked. I thought that when I link a .a library to the .dll it will be linked inside it but I guess not. I will have to do more research about this then.